# What does microtask runs after every callback mean?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm reading [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) on microtasks and there is the following conclusion:

> In summary:
>
> - Tasks execute in order, and the browser may render between them
> - Microtasks execute in order, and are executed:
>
>   - after every callback,
>   - as long as no other JavaScript is mid-execution at the end of each
>       task

As I understand each task represents a single VM turn, so *as long as no other JavaScript is mid-execution at the end of each task* means when call stack is empty. But I don't understand what *after every callback* mean?

Can anyone please explain and show an example?

Comment: I find that wording confusing indeed. I suppose the author means with `callback` not the kind of self-implemented callback (e.g. `function f(callback) { callback() }; f(_ => alert('hi'));`, but the ones that the DOM implementation invokes in response to some event. With the first kind, the call stack would not (always) be empty (so it does not apply), but the second kind sounds to me as just another task, initiated by an event in the event queue, and ending when the associated call stack is back to empty. I think you need to ask the author.

Comment: Reading the article, it's pretty clear, but I'm not sure how to explain it better than the article did.  As @trincot said, it's talking about the JS engine internals and how it schedules execution of synchronous and asynchronous tasks.  So the mechanism by which they make sure your callback is scheduled and called, and the call stack is managed.

Comment: I interpret that as saying "callback in reference to returning execution state".

Comment: @trincot, yes, you are right, thanks, I think I've figured  it out. I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44485485/2545680).

Comment: Without a clear definition of "callback", that wording is useless. And "*JavaScript in mid-execution at the end of a task*" doesn't make any sense either

Comment: @Bergi, yes, you're right, that's why I posted the question. But it seems that I've come up with an example to at least understand what the author meant.

Comment: @Maximus After reading the entire article, I think the author was confused by `inner.click()`, which synchronously executes DOM listeners. And is probably very confusing in the spec as well when it's described in terms of tasks that are usually asynchronous, in their own stack.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for your comment, I asked the author to comment. Btw, were you familiar with microtask queue? I haven't read about it before

Comment: @Bergi, here is the consversation with the author https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/873963014986379265

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the clear example that demonstrates this:

```
function cb1() {
    console.log('cb1');
    Promise.resolve('df').then(function promiseMicrotask() {
        console.log('promise');
    });
}

function cb2() {
    console.log('cb2');
}

const element = document.querySelector('div.inner');
element.addEventListener('click', cb1);
element.addEventListener('click', cb2);
```

In the example above when you click on the `div.inner`, a browser schedules a task to handle the event and call the callbacks `cb1` and `cb2`. Later it starts executing the task and triggers `cb1`. Inside `cb1` a resolved promise schedules a microtask to run the `promiseMicrotask` callback. Whenever the current stack that started with `cb1` is empty the browser  checks the microtaks queue and finds a microtask `promiseMicrotask`. It triggers it and so it logs `promise`. Then it proceeds to triggering `cb2`.

So the microtask `promiseMicrotask` was processed *after the callback* `cb1` but before `cb2` and before the browser finished executing all callbacks in the current task.

What's important here is that all event callbacks are executed in current task.

Comment: Good! As noted in the article, the behaviour is not the same in all browsers. This is the behaviour in Chrome (v59), Edge (v40), but not in Firefox (v53).

Comment: @trincot, yeah, it's weird the newest versions of firefox still haven't fixed it. Btw, here is the discussion with the author https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/873963014986379265